# Azure Cloud restrict amount of requests from same IP per minute

Tags: azure

I am having an issue with a server where someone is sending thousands of requests from same IP in a minute. How do you limit amount of requests per minute per IP on Azure and if possible ban the IP temporary or permanently after that?

Comment: This should be posted to ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: Please edit your question to explain how you deployed your app (VM? Web app? cloud service?). Even better, just repost in ServerFault, including that extra information.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to Permanently Ban a specific IP use an IPsec policy in your VM.
Find the details in the below link
http://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserversecurity/ipsec-blockip/

Otherwise If you Can to do it programatically. This is basically to prevent DDOS attacks. Please go through the below links
http://omaralzabir.com/prevent_denial_of_service__dos__attacks_in_your_web_application/

In Case You want to limit the no of requests from an IP
http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/iptables-rate-limit-incoming.html

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using a Windows VM (and not linux, and not Web Apps). And you're also not considering Azure-specific inbound security rules.

Comment: Also, answers that don't provide details and only link to external sites are frowned upon because those links could become stale and make the answer useless.

Comment: Please see my Edited post.

Comment: Now three link-only answers instead of one?